# Does Google Feed API add XML tags that are missing?

Tags: javascript, xml, rss, google-feed-api

I have inherited a piece of Javascript that uses the Google Feed API.
It calls this feed and returns XML from TypePad:
http://simplystated.realsimple.com/simplystated/adventures-in-chaos/rss.xml
If I view this feed using Firefox's View Source, I see the underlying XML.  There is a <dc:creator> XML tag.

After calling the API, when I look at the results.xmlDocument, I notice that there is an <author> field that was not there before.

Does the Google Feed API normalize the feed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I understand it, you don't get the original feed; you get a feed from Google's servers. Google loads the original feed and then feeds it back to you. Since you can even change the feed format (like to JSON or XML) I think it's safe to assume that Google will always transform and normalize it before giving it back to you.